# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread ... DiscordPy MultiThreading

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, discord.py

so I have a python script where I want to run multiple discord bots at the same time. These are defined by how many users there are in the database (Firebase). What I now do is that I have an loop for every user in the database it add's it to an array. Then for every user in that array it starts a script:

```
def main(user):

        client = discord.Client()

        token = db.child("users").child(user).child("token").get().val()
        print(user + ": " + token)

        applicationId = db.child("users").child(user).child("appid").get().val()

        discordId = user

        @client.event
        async def on_ready():
                print('Online')

        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
                print(message)
        client.start(token, bot=False)

def testFunction(some_args):
        print(some_args)
        discord_thread = threading.Thread(target=main, args=(some_args,))
        discord_thread.start()

for user in usersArray:
        testFunction(user)
```

When I start the script it works until the client.start part. Then I get an error for every thread. 
Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jonah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "discordnotify.py", line 39, in main
    client = discord.Client()
  File "C:\Users\jonah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() if loop is None else loop
  File "C:\Users\jonah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

Is there anyone who can maybe help me somehow? It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use threading when running multiple discord bots. You can view [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/516) for some more info, but I can lay it out for you right now. Fixing how you start your discord bots will help you a ton.

For starters, you have to realise that `Client.run` is an abstraction of a couple of more lower level concepts.

There is `Client.login` which logs in the client and then `Client.connect` which actually runs the processing. These are coroutines.

`asyncio` provides the capability of putting things in the event loop for it to work whenever it has time to.

Something like this e.g.

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def foo():
  await asyncio.sleep(10)
  loop.close()

loop.create_task(foo())
loop.run_forever()
```

If we want to wait for something to happen from another coroutine, asyncio provides us with this functionality as well through the means of synchronisation via asyncio.Event. You can consider this as a boolean that you are waiting for:

```py
e = asyncio.Event()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def foo():
  await e.wait()
  print('we are done waiting...')
  loop.stop()

async def bar():
  await asyncio.sleep(20)
  e.set()

loop.create_task(bar())
loop.create_task(foo())
loop.run_forever() # foo will stop this event loop when 'e' is set to true
loop.close()
```

Using this concept we can apply it to the discord bots themselves.

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from collections import namedtuple

# First, we must attach an event signalling when the bot has been
# closed to the client itself so we know when to fully close the event loop.

Entry = namedtuple('Entry', 'client event')
entries = [
  Entry(client=discord.Client(), event=asyncio.Event()),
  Entry(client=discord.Client(), event=asyncio.Event())
]

# Then, we should login to all our clients and wrap the connect call
# so it knows when to do the actual full closure

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def login():
  for e in entries:
    await e.client.login()

async def wrapped_connect(entry):
  try:
    await entry.client.connect()
  except Exception as e:
    await entry.client.close()
    print('We got an exception: ', e.__class__.__name__, e)
    entry.event.set()

# actually check if we should close the event loop:
async def check_close():
  futures = [e.event.wait() for e in entries]
  await asyncio.wait(futures)

# here is when we actually login
loop.run_until_complete(login())

# now we connect to every client
for entry in entries:
  loop.create_task(wrapped_connect(entry))

# now we're waiting for all the clients to close
loop.run_until_complete(check_close())

# finally, we close the event loop
loop.close()
```